How to create uniform bin widths in gnuplot?

I want each bin to be the same width, but since there are no values in some ranges (Ex: 10 to 15),  gnuplot is automatically increasing its width to fit the space 10 to 20.
I have set the bins like so:
binwidth=5
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)
plot 'Module 2 Mod*100.txt' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) \
      smooth freq with boxes linecolor rgb "#FFCCE5" title ''

How can I fix this?

Shortest answer in your case (check help boxwidth):
set boxwidth binwidth

Keep in mind that the boxes plotted via with boxes will be centered around the x-value. If you have a histogram then you maybe want the boxes ranging, e.g. from 0 to 5, from 5 to 10, etc. Then you have to add half a binwidth.
A minimal example for illustration:
Script:
### equal boxwith in histogram
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 20
    plot '+' u (rand(0)*100):(rand(0)*100) w table
unset table

set style fill solid 0.3
set key noautotitle
set tics out
set offset 1,1,0,0
set grid x,y
set xrange [0:100]
set xtic 10
binwidth     = 5
bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width)

set multiplot layout 3,1
    set linestyle 1 lc "red"
    plot $Data u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) \
         smooth freq with boxes ls 1

    set boxwidth binwidth
    set linestyle 1 lc "green"
    replot
    
    bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width) + binwidth/2.
    set linestyle 1 lc "blue"
    replot
unset multiplot
### end of script

Result:

